# WSO2 How to specify number of days for which the account is inactive in the reminder email

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have been setting up "Idle account locking" for WSO2 from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/User+Account+Suspension)
It works very well, and emails are being sent on the days you specify.

I am trying to edit the email template for the `idleAccountReminder`.
The default template only contains only one dynamic field which is `{{user.claim.givenname}}`.

The default template looks like this:

> Hi {{user.claim.givenname}},
>
> It looks as though you haven't signed in to your account for quite a
>   while. Please sign in to your account if you'd like to keep your
>   account active.

I want to replace the phrase 'quite a while' with the exact number of days the account has not been use for.
I am hoping something like this:

> Hi {{user.claim.givenname}},
>
> It looks as though you haven't signed in to your account for
>   {{user.daysUnusedFor}} days. Please sign in to your account if you'd
>   like to keep your account active.

1. How do I get the number of days in the email template ?
2. Where can I find the documentation that describes all the available variables (dynamic fields) I can use to customise the email templates

Answer (score 0):

Refer [1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Customizing+Automated+Emails#CustomizingAutomatedEmails-Editinganemailtemplate), and see how user claims can be injected into email templates. I'm not sure if we can inject the number of days as a placeholder.

[1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Customizing+Automated+Emails#CustomizingAutomatedEmails-Editinganemailtemplate)[https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Customizing+Automated+Emails#CustomizingAutomatedEmails-Editinganemailtemplate][1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Customizing+Automated+Emails#CustomizingAutomatedEmails-Editinganemailtemplate)